# reload after customize

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

i have a very [simple firefox addon](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1021651/latest/) that essentially just displays the total number of open tabs.

So far it works beautifully, however after right clicking on the toolbar and selecting *Customize…* it only shows the default text until a tab is opened or closed.

i presume that i need to add an event listener for this event and call `updateWidget()`, however i can't find it in the API doc. So does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I think that this is a bug - the widget module simply doesn't handle toolbar customization correctly. You should [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Add-on%20SDK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verified as bug, see : [bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=773297](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=773297)